# Ansible nested loops using value form one loop to another

Tags: loops, nested

I am facing issue while writing nested loops in ansible, for below iteration I am getting error
ansible role I am using looks like below

The conditional check 'item[0]['value']['from'] == COMPONENT_NAME' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item[0]['value']['from'] == COMPONENT_NAME): 'item' is undefined

Role

```
- name: create config file 
  template:
    src: "{{template_source}}/{{COMPONENT_NAME}}/sessions/{{ item[0]['value']['protocol']}}/{{item[0]['value']['from_template']}}"
    dest: "{{dest_folder}}/{{app}}/{{instance_name}}/{{COMPONENT_NAME}}/{{VENUE}}/Config/Repo/session/{{item[0]['value']['protocol']}}/{{item[1]}}.json"
    mode: 0755
  vars:
    dest_file_name: "{{instance_name}}_{{COMPONENT_NAME}}_{{VENUE}}_{{item[0]['key']}}"
    mbFlag: "{{item[0]['value']['broker'] |  default('False')}}"
  when: item[0]['value']['from'] == COMPONENT_NAME
  with_nested:
    - "{{ connections | dict2items }}"
    - "{{myFileList['from_' + COMPONENT_NAME +'_'+ VENUE +'_'+ item[0]['value']['to']].split(',') }}"
```

yml file having below variable and I am iterating over it.

```
myFileList: 
   {
    from_et_AG_zp: DevOpsTest_et_zp_AG_zp, 
    from_et_AG_sSP: 'DevOpsTest_et_sSP_AG_US,DevOpsTest_et_sSP_AG_BA,DevOpsTest_et_sSP_AG_chex',
    from_et_AG_esb: DevOpsTest_et_esb_AG_ABC, 
    from_et_BA_Y_zp: DevOpsTest_et_zp_BA_Y_zp,
    from_et_BA_Y_sSP: 'DevOpsTest_et_sSP_BA_Y_US,DevOpsTest_et_sSP_BA_Y_BA,DevOpsTest_et_sSP_BA_Y_chex',
    from_et_BA_Y_esb: DevOpsTest_et_esb_BA_Y_ABC, 
    from_et_BA_zp: DevOpsTest_et_zp_BA_zp,
    from_et_BA_sSP: 'DevOpsTest_et_sSP_BA_US,DevOpsTest_et_sSP_BA_BA,DevOpsTest_et_sSP_BA_chex',
    from_et_BA_esb: DevOpsTest_et_esb_BA_ABC, 
    from_zp_zp_esb: DevOpsTest_zp_esb_zp_ABC,
    from_SP_SP_esb: DevOpsTest_SP_esb_SP_ABC, 
    from_SSS_SSS_esb: DevOpsTest_SSS_esb_SSS_ABC,
    
    to_zp_zp_es: DevOpsTest_et_zp_zp_es, 
    to_sSP_BA_es: DevOpsTest_et_sSP_BA_es,
    to_sSP_chex_es: DevOpsTest_et_sSP_chex_es, 
    to_sSP_US_es: DevOpsTest_et_sSP_US_es,
    to_esb_ABC_es: DevOpsTest_et_esb_ABC_es, 
    to_esb_ABC_zp: DevOpsTest_zp_esb_ABC_zp,
    to_esb_ABC_SP: DevOpsTest_SP_esb_ABC_SP, 
    to_esb_ABC_SSS: DevOpsTest_SSS_esb_ABC_SSS
    
    }



connections:
  et_etb:
    from: et
    to: etb
    from_template: et_etb.json
    to_template: etb_et.json
    protocol: ZERO
```

Comment: can you print item[0]['value']['from'] before using it in when module? debug: var=item[0]['value']['from']

Comment: Hi Saurabh , I tried printing that it is still giving same error in debug

Comment: show output of item[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After too many permutation and combination, I realize that we can not pass outer loop variable value  from outer loop to inner loop, So as work around I write first loop in first role and second loop in another role and call second role from first by iterating over first loop that full fill my ends

```
---
- name: create config file
  include_role:
    name: patch_template
  vars:
    file_key: "{{ 'from_' + COMPONENT_NAME +'_'+ VENUE +'_'+ role_item.value.to }}"
    myprotocol: "{{role_item.value.protocol}}"
    myTemplate: "{{role_item.value.from_template}}"
    subComponent: "{{VENUE}}"
   

  when: role_item.value.from == COMPONENT_NAME
  with_items: "{{ connections | dict2items }}"

  loop_control:
    loop_var: role_item
```

patch_template role file

```
- name: patch template
  template:
    src: "{{template_source}}/{{COMPONENT_NAME}}/sessions/{{myprotocol}}/{{myTemplate}}"
    dest: "{{dest_folder}}/{{app}}/{{instance_name}}/{{COMPONENT_NAME}}/{{subComponent}}/Config/Repo/session/{{myprotocol}}/{{item}}.json"
    mode: 0755
  vars:
    dest_file_name: "{{item}}"
  with_items:
     - "{{ myFileList[file_key].split(',') }}"
```